# Intent.getExtras not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In one class, I have the following variables declared outside of the onCreate method:

```
Double isowei2 = 9.36;  
Double iso2 = 10.54;
```

Inside the onCreate method, I have this:

```
final Intent start = new Intent(IsoAbun.this, IsoAbunCal.class);
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        isowei2 = 9.0;  
        iso2 = isowei2;  
        start.putExtra("iso2", iso2);  
        startActivity(start);  
    }
```

Those two code were in one class. In another class, I have this in the onCreate method:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Double iiso2 = 0.0;
    iiso2 = b.getDouble("iso2");
```

From what I understand from this, what it should do is when I click on the button from the first class, it reassignes `isowei2` to 9.0, sets `iso2` to 9.0, then creates a key called iso2, passing in the value of `iso2`, which is 9.0, then starts the intent/activity. When it starts the activity, what it should do is create a bundle and a double variable, then sets `iiso2` to `iso2`, which is 9.0. I have unshown code that displays the value of `iiso2`, but the problem is it does not display 9.0, instead if displays 10.54. Any help?

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: Have you tried changing Double to double? Double is an object whereas double is primitive type.

Comment: Could you add the two classes as is ?

Comment: I would start with suggestion made by michaelcarrano.

Comment: @michaelcarrano That has no change

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have something setup like this in your onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.<your layout>);
final Intent start = new Intent(this, <OtherClass>.class);
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnId);//find from your activity xml, your button Id
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    isowei2 = 9.0;  
            iso2 = isowei2;  
            start.putExtra("iso2", iso2);  
            startActivity(start);
                    }           
            });
}
```

In another class oncreate method, you can view it by using a TextView for example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Double iiso2 = 0.0;
    iiso2 = b.getDouble("iso2");
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText(iiso2.toString());
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

If you don't have an id assigned for your button, here is an example of how it looks like in your layout xml :

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Comment: when a separate method that's assigned to android:onClick in layout is NOT used , this is how it should be done in onCreate method.please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html to know about various ways of responding to click events

Comment: I understand how implementing onClick works. The point was you didn't explain anything. But the problem isn't with the button click. The OP can get to the next activity just fine but is displaying the wrong data there.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this is different? I don't see much difference

Comment: I did the whole thing what the question was about, and I can see correct data 9.0 displayed in the second activity when I clicked the button in the first activity, so something else might be the problem but the code in onclick worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the data as an intent extra, create a bundle with the data and pass that bundle through the intent.

So something like:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDouble("key", myDouble);
startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
```

Then in the receiving activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null)
    double myDouble = bundle.getDouble("key");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I think what's happening is that after the variables are changed in the onCreate method, a new activity is started. When the new activity starts it deletes the old information from the old onCreate method, and erasing the changes done. So when I try to access it, it views that no change happened, and therefore giving me the default values. That's my guess on this problem, but my coding experience doesn't tell me how to solve it. Would you have any idea?